# Netflix Desktop not working after update

Tags: upgrade, netflix

Netflix Desktop was working fine until I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 today. Now, it gives me the message that the silverlight plugin has crashed. I tried different workarounds and to even downgrade my silverlight version to 4--apparently 5 does not work.

I would appreciate help with this issue, and I'm sure I'm not the only one experiencing it.

Comment: I tried Pipelight as well without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! Actually, I was able to solve it a few days ago using the last few comments **[here](http://answers.launchpad.net/netflix-desktop/+question/237615)**. It was determined that my issue had something to do with hw-acceleration. I didn't get the chance to post back here.

Answer (score 2):

you need to uninstall netflix-desktop and wine-compholio by purging them both

```
apt-get purge netflix-desktop wine-compholio
```

After this is done follow the instructions here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

If you tried pipelight without success do this:

`sudo pipelight-plugin --disable-all`

`sudo rm /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libpipelight.so`

`pipelight-plugin --disable-all`

In my case the problem was related to hardware acceleration. Running netflix desktop using the command below worked for me:

wine-browser --disable-hw-acceleration

If the above works for you you can make changes to the launcher that will stick until the next update to netflix-desktop by issuing the following commands:

`sudo mv /usr/share/wine-browser-installer/hw-accel-default /usr/share/wine-browser-installer/hw-accel-default2`

`echo -e '#!/bin/sh\nexit 1;' | sudo tee /usr/share/wine-browser-installer/hw-accel-default`

`sudo chmod +x /usr/share/wine-browser-installer/hw-accel-default`

Source: https://answers.launchpad.net/netflix-desktop/+question/237615